# Adding AUC to legend and optimal threshold value to plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc

I am using ggplot to create a graph with multiple ROC curves overlaid. I want to add the optimal threshold (Youden's threshold) to each line and add the AUC for each line to the legend.

```
test <- ggplot() +
geom_roc(aes(d= rad.opacity, m=opacity.score, colour="Opacity"), labels=FALSE, subset1) + 
geom_roc(aes(d= rad.fibrosis, m=fibrosis.score, colour="Fibrosis"), labels=FALSE, subset1) +
  annotate(
    labels = paste("AUC =", round(calc_auc(test)["AUC"], 2))) +
  style_roc(xlab = "1 - Specificity", ylab = "Sensitivity")
```

I tried the above code to add the AUC but it isn't working. It returns "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 10 needed but only 0 provided."

Not sure what to try for the optimal threshold value...

Comment: I don't see any data argument given to ggplot(), and I don't see any test data for us to show you how it should have been done, so voting to close. See [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this platform! The data set is "subset 1". I am able to generate the plot I just can't add the annotations that I need (AUC, optimal threshold). How else can I help clarify my question?

Comment: I don't think the point is getting through to you. You need to either use a dataset that we all have on our machines (like `mtcars`) or you need to write some code to paste into your question to make a dataset with the same general structure as what you are using. Base R plotting makes it very easy to overlay graphics, `ggplot` not so much. `ggplot` need the data to be reworked or use + geom_line with a different dataset.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try using base R

Comment: You could check out the cutpointr package (Disclaimer: I'm the author) which does what you want to do. After calculating the cutpoints you can plot multiple ROC curves and the optimal thresholds with `plot_roc` which returns a ggplot that you can modify further. You'll have to annotate the AUCs manually, though. Try `cutpointr(suicide, dsi, suicide, gender, metric = youden) %>% plot_roc()` as an example.